# Select from table named as MySQL keyword

Tags: mysql, keyword-argument

I have table created by `ORM` named 'key'. 'key' is MySQL keyword so I cannot select it just `SELECT * FROM key;`.

How to perform select from table named 'key' in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape your table name with backticks `

```
SELECT * FROM `key`
```

This will make your database understand `key` is a table

Comment: That works! I tried to use regular quotes, but it works only with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
select * from [key]
```